# PyQt5 creating pdfs using pdfkit - wkhtmltopdf.exe window popup with each pdf

Tags: python, pyqt5, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, fbs

I've built an application using PyQt5 to process some data and generate a pdf report using pdfkit. If I run the application through PyCharm this works well. I've packaged the application into an executable using fman build system (PyInstaller wrapper) and when I run it, a wkhtmltopdf.exe console window pops up every time a pdf is generated.

This is really annoying when processing many files.

Is there a way to ensure wkhtmltopdf.exe only ever opens as a minimized window (or similar solution)?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but the issue lay in the executable so I didn't know how to post a reproducible example of someone creating (even a simple) PyQt5 gui using the specific folder structure of fbs and then packaging it just to create a pdf

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resorted to forking pdfkit from GitHub and adding `creationflags=0x08000000` in the `Popen` functions in the `configuration.py` and `pdfkit.py`files. I knew I would be passing the `wkhtmltopdf.exe` location to the configuration file so I made this explicit as well.

It's available at https://github.com/KiFi85/python-pdfkit

It worked for me but not sure if it's the best solution